# Эффективный алгоритм поиска общих сегментов полигональной геометрии

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, карты, структуры-данных, вычислительная-геометрия

Разрабатываю картографический движок для морских навигационных карт. В стандарте указано, что если участки линий друг на друга накладываются (имеют общие сегменты), то участок линии с наименьшим приоритетом (каждая геометрия имеет приоритет) должен быть скрыт. 
Я не могу понять как это выразить алгоритмически. Первым делом пробовал перебирать все линии, и удалять общие точки, что в корне неверно, т.к оставшиеся точки соединялись и менялась сама геометрия линий. Плюс производительность жуткая: для каждой линии, перебираем все линии и точки... Одна такая линия может содержать 4 тысячи точек. А линий на экране может быть более тысячи.

Проще говоря, необходимо найти и скрыть общие сегменты у полигональной геометрии и сделать это довольно эффективно.

В аналогичном проприетарном софте такой функционал реализован и работает довольно быстро. Наверняка есть какие-то общепринятые решения данной задачи.

Снизу вырезка из стандарта.

[image: вырезка из стандарта]

Снизу представлен скриншот, на котором видно как линия, обозначающая опасную область (в виде фиолетового паттерна с восклицательным знаком) имеет общие грани с береговой линией и линией причала. Поскольку эти линии имеют больший приоритет, то линия, обозначающая границы области должна быть скрыта в этих сегментах. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так это должно выглядеть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эээ...Рисовать в порядку увеличения приоритета?

Comment: Линии -- это прямые? Как они задаются? Что понимается под наложением?

Comment: @MBo нет. По порядку получится только с простыми линиями. Большинство линий имеют сложный паттерн, вроде символов якорей и тд. При наложении будет видно обе линии.

Comment: @hedgehogues Большинство линий задаются полигонами и обозначают границы области. Реже- полилинией (набором точек).

Comment: @PavelSaenko как линии могут задаваться полигонами и точками одновременно? И как они могут задаваться полигонами вообще?

Comment: @hedgehogues. Не одновременно. В картах стандарта S57 есть такие виды геометрии как Polygon и Polyline. Полигонами обозначаются некоторые области на карте. Полиниями - какие-то пути и маршруты. Но в данном случае можно рассматривать только полигоны, т.к. полигональной геометрии на картах куда больше и именно области чаще всего имеют общие сегменты.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что Вам нужно найти линию пересечения полигонов и убрать ту чать пересечения, которая менее приоритетна?

Comment: @hedgehogues все верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался. Необходимо было пройтись по всей геометрии и создать хэш-словарь с сегментом (две точки отрезка) в качестве ключа и массивом с указателями на геометрию, которой принадлежит этот сегмент - в качестве значения. Таким образом получилось однозначно определить скольким полигонам принадлежит каждый сегмент. 
Затем надо снова пройтись по всей геометрии, и ее сегментам. По словарю, который мы создали в предыдущем пункте, получаем массив геометрии, которому этот отрезок тоже принадлежит. Смотрим, есть ли в этом списке геометрия с бОльшим приоритетом чем текущая, ели да, то отмечаем данный отрезок как игнорируемый. 
Для того чтобы хранить информацию об игнорируемых отрезках, я использую массив булевых значений, где индекс в массиве соответствует номеру сегмента. 
В виде кода это выглядит так:

```
struct Edge {

    QPointF a,b;

};
// Создаем и заполняем хэш-карту всех имеющихся сегментов 
   QMultiHash<Edge, S57Feature*> sharedEdges;

    for (const auto feature: chart->features) {


                for (int i = 0; i < feature->pt.size(); i++) {

                    Edge edge {feature->pt[i],feature->pt[i+1]};
                    sharedEdges.insert(edge,feature);

                }


    }

// Проверяем совпадает ли каждый сегмент с другой геометрией более высокого приоритета
for (const auto feature: chart->features) {


                feature->suppressed_edges.resize(feature->npts());
                for (int i = 0; i < feature->pt.size(); i++) {

                    Edge edge {feature->pt[i],feature->pt[i+1]};
                    auto values = sharedEdges.values( edge );

                    for (const auto v : values) {

                        if (v->order > feature->order){
                            feature->suppressed_edges[i] = true;

                            break;
                        }

                    }


        }


    }
```